# Aplicar javascript ao ng-include

Tags: angularjs

Estou usando "ng-include" para adicionar o menu em uma página, ele carrega o menu, porém o javascript para de funcionar.

Não tenho muito conhecimento em angularjs.

Está assim no html:

```
<script src="/../js/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script src="/../js/angular-route.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    
<section ng-include src="'/../header.min.html'"></section>
    

<script>
   $('.navbar .dropdown .fa').on('click', function (){
   $(this).parent('li').children('.dropdown-menu').slideToggle();
   });
</script>
```

O que eu teria que fazer para funcionar o javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que esteja com esse problema por utilizar errado o `ngInclude`, se você verificar a [documentação](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude), as maneiras corretas de se utilizar seriam:

Ou utilizar como um elemento e coloca o caminho para o `.html` no atributo `src`:

```html
<ng-include src="'/../header.min.html'"></ng-include>
```

Ou utilizar como diretiva, assim como já esta utilizando, porém atribuir caminho para o `.html` à própria diretiva e não a um novo atributo `src`:

```html
<section ng-include="'/../header.min.html'"></section>
```

Comment: Não tive sucesso, tentei das duas formas.

Comment: Aparece algum erro no console do navegador?

Comment: Não apareceu erros, apenas uma referencia de fonte